# How to change the font color of the result after pressing the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the font color of the result after pressing the button. And how to make a certain gif appear in case of a win and another in case of a loss? This is a code to check if a ticket is a winner or a loser. And I would like to change the color to the result and the font type. I would also like a different gif based on the final result.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var oImageDiv=document.getElementById("WinnerGif");

function get(){
var t1 = document.getElementById("text1").value
var t2 = document.getElementById("text2").value
var t3 = document.getElementById("text3").value
document.getElementById("textarea").value = t1+t2+t3;
}

var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var formArea = document.getElementById("formArea");

var zips = ["2222222222"];

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var result = null;


  // indexOf() returns -1 when the supplied value isn't present
  if (zips.indexOf(textarea.value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    result = "VINCENTE";
        oImageDiv.style.display=(oImageDiv.style.display=='none')?'inline':'none';
    // Show the form by removing the hidden class
  } else {
    result = "NON VINCENTE";
    // Hide the form by adding the hidden class
    formArea.classList.add("hidden");
  }
  output.textContent = result;
});

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.onkeyup = function (e) {
  var target = e.srcElement;
  var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
  var myLength = target.value.length;
  if (myLength >= maxLength) {
    var next = target;
    while ((next = next.nextElementSibling)) {
      if (next == null) break;
      if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        next.focus();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
   color:    #FFFFFF;
}
.check-number-form .number-list-wrapper .number-list input {
    width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
  
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
135deg
, #2243e6 0%, #63fff8 100%);
  
   
 margin:32px;
padding: 10px;
max-width: 180px;

display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
  
  
    
    
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #c4cbf9;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.cmn-btn {
    
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 999px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
  left: 42px;
  right: 133px;
   
   
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(86deg, #ec038b 0%, #fb6468 44%, #fbb936 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
86deg
, #ec038b 0%, #fb6468 44%, #fbb936 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(86deg, #ec038b 0%, #fb6468 44%, #fbb936 100%);
   
    webkit-transition: background-size 0.3s;
    o-transition: background-size 0.3s;
    transition: background-size 0.3s;
    color: #ffffff;
}
[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {
    webkit-appearance: button;
}

button {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="WinnerGif" style="display:none;">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_xldzoar8.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"  loop  autoplay></lottie-player>

</div>
                        

<form class="check-number-form">
<div class="number-list-wrapper">
<div class="number-list mt-3 mb-3">
<div class="container">

<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" placeholder="0000" maxlength="4" >
                            <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" placeholder="0000" maxlength="4">
                            <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" placeholder="00" maxlength="2">
<type="hidden" textarea id='textarea'></type>
  

</div>


<button type="button" id="btn" class="cmn-btn" onclick='get();' style="width:265.63px; height:57px" >Controlla il mio biglietto</button>

<p id="demo" ></p>

<div id="formArea" class="hidden"   >

  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add id to text and onclick event to button :

```
<p id="myH2">Hello World</p>
<button onick=color()></button>
```

Then use JavaScript to change font color when button is pressed :

```
function color(){
document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```

Hope that answers your question.